I am unable to use native code in my Flutter application after the app has been killed
I am experiencing an issue with my Flutter application. When the application is killed and then restarted, the Flutter method channel is not being created. As a result, I am unable to use native code in my Flutter application after the app has been killed. However, if the app is not killed, everything works fine.
When the app is killed and this issue occurs, I encounter the following error:
-> Tried to send a platform message to Flutter, but FlutterJNI was detached from native C++. Could not send. Channel: com.example.inyourskin. Response ID:
